# mocking dsp's in header bidding

Tags: prebid.js, header-bidding

is it possible to hard code the return from the bidders in header bidding , like is it possible to mock the function of bidders like appnexus and other for learning and playing around ? 
like a bidder generally returns :

adunit    aId       bidder     time     cpm
"QzxcU6"  "106oF"   Appnexus    400     0.082367

Comment: adunit, aId ,bidder, time, cpm  are "QzxcU6" ,"106oF" ,"Appnexus", "400","0.082367" respectively

Comment: adunit, aId ,bidder, time, cpm  are "QzxcU6" ,"106oF" ,"Appnexus", "400","0.082367" respectively

Answer (score 0):

#### option 1

If you just want to play with it in your browser you can simply change requested domains in your `/etc/hosts` file to point at your `localhost` and bring up a local server serving the response you need.

#### option 2

you can download [prebid.js](https://github.com/prebid/Prebid.js), patch locally whatever you need and build your own version

#### option 3

If you need it for tests just check out how other tests are written i.e. [appnexus's ones](https://github.com/prebid/Prebid.js/blob/master/test/spec/modules/appnexusBidAdapter_spec.js)

Answer (score 0):

You would have to modify the modules in prebid in order to get them to work like that. Generally if you want to test things I'd recommend running a house campaign to those placements (or via a segment pixel segment).

You could then use a [bid CPM adjustment in pbjs.bidderSettings](http://prebid.org/dev-docs/publisher-api-reference.html#module_pbjs.bidderSettings) to set the values returned to be a particular price if you'd like